# How to remove points from point cloud using PCL?

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library, pcl

I'm using PCL library and RTAB-Map for maps generation. When the video is too long, the map post-processing takes too much time, so I would like to make this process lighter. In order to that, I would like to remove the already processed points (or older) from the incoming map, and take only the new ones, so I could process them faster.

I've seen in some posts that people use this (or other segmentation techniques to get the inliers or indices):

```
vector<int> inliers;
// Plane model
pcl::SampleConsensusModelPlane<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr model_p (new pcl::SampleConsensusModelPlane<pcl::PointXYZRGB> (cloud_buffer));

pcl::RandomSampleConsensus<pcl::PointXYZRGB> ransac (model_p);
ransac.getInliers(inliers);

pcl::PointIndices::Ptr fInliers (new pcl::PointIndices);
fInliers->indices = inliers;

pcl::ExtractIndices<pcl::PointXYZRGB> extract;
extract.setInputCloud (cloud);
extract.setIndices (fInliers);
extract.setNegative(false);
extract.filter(*cloud);
```

But in my case, it doesn't work to me. It uses the RANSAC with Plane Model, and I think this way it takes no inliers with my data. I would like to take all the points from the cloud and delete all of them in the next iteration, in order to work only with the new ones.

How could it be the best way to do this process? I think that using the code below is the way, but I don't know how to select all the indices in my point cloud, without using RANSAC or any other segmentation technique.

```
pcl::ExtractIndices<pcl::PointXYZRGB> extract;
extract.setInputCloud (cloud);
extract.setIndices (fInliers);
extract.setNegative(false);
extract.filter(*cloud);
```

Thanks in advance.